# How often is a tire replaced on a 777?

Tags: landing-gear, boeing-777, tire

Given that it is long haul aircraft, and is most widely used by airlines in that capacity:

1. How often do they replace the whole tire?
2. How much does 1 tire cost the airline?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aircraft tires are replaced on condition, but maingear tires usually last about [250 cycles](https://www.lufthansa-technik.com/landing-gear-overhaul). A 777 in longhaul usage might only get two cycles a day, so a set of tires would last about four months.

The 777 uses a [50x20.0r22](https://www.goodyearaviation.com/resources/tiredatabook.html) with 32ply rating. I couldn't find that exact tire but a similar one costs [$4700 new](https://www.skygeek.com/goodyear-501k02-1-tire-50x21-0-20-30-fldr-tl-301-734-220.html). It is common practice to retread or remold worn tires after inspecting the carcass to ensure its serviceability, and these cost about half of new.

Interestingly, [this study](https://commons.erau.edu/ijaaa/vol2/iss1/2/) by Embry-Riddle suggests that 99% of tire wear could be eliminated by prespinning the tires prior to touchdown, eliminating the puff of smoke you see as a part of the tire burns away as it matches up to relative runway speed. If correct, a tire would effectively last forever, until it was damaged as by debris or a hard landing.

Comment: [Here's more information about pre-spinning tires before landing](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/why-are-aircraft-tires-not-pre-spun-prior-to-landing-to-preserve-them).

Comment: Very informative. Appreciate the detailed response!

Comment: That's about half the price of a tire for a Bugatti Veyron.