# Would this modified tire work to prespin an aircraft tire?

Tags: aircraft-design, landing, fixed-wing, tire, modifications

In order to decrease that initial hit of the tire spinning up to ground speed on the runway, could adding a blades or shape into the tire rim of a commercial plane save on tires by prespinning the tire like a pin-wheel prior to landing?

Related: [Why are aircraft tires not pre-spun prior to landing to preserve them?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3702/why-are-aircraft-tires-not-pre-spun-prior-to-landing-to-preserve-them)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Cheaper just to recap the tires over and over until the carcass is shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is good in concept but it would be pretty difficult to match the rpms to the actuual ground speed, in fact if the wheel was spinning faster it would actually wear the tyre more!

Another factor is that aircraft wheels often do not hit the runway straight on. In a crosswind situation they could be off a few degrees so the tyre would still scrub.

Also the fact that adding weight is anathema to airplane designers, not only the motors but electronic controllers and associated wiring. This weight will have to be carried for the duration of the flight.

Finally the hardest working part is not the tyre but the wheel bearings.. on a longer widebody flight they go from cold-soaked to very hot in a few seconds. Tyres actually fare pretty well, I've seen new tyres fitted and come back after a few sectors which still looked pretty new.

As mentioned by John K in the comments above, its cheaper to recap they tyre.