# How do plane landing-gear tyres roll before take off?

Tags: landing-gear

How do plane tyres roll? Are they equipped with special engines like cars or are they rolling using the plane flying engines? Or can both methods be found with different constructors?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Related: [How does an aircraft taxi?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/956/how-does-an-aircraft-taxi), also  [Does it make sense towing airplanes to the head of airstrip by external means?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9101/does-it-make-sense-towing-airplanes-to-the-head-of-airstrip-by-external-means) and last [What is the cost savings of using electronic motors to taxi?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16874/what-is-the-cost-savings-of-using-electronic-motors-to-taxi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, aircraft wheels are rotating freely around their axle, unless the brakes are activated. The ground roll was a convenient time for engine warm-up in the days of piston aircraft.

However, rolling on the ground using jet engines is very inefficient; fuel consumption could be reduced if the aircraft uses other means of propulsion on the ground and only starts the engines right before take-off. Therefore, electric propulsion using hub motors is actively studied. The batteries could be charged (partially) during landing, when the hub motors are switched to generator mode, and the rest of the power could be provided by the APU.

Pushing back from the gate using jet engines is unwise, so a tug is used to move the aircraft to a position from which it can continue the ground roll to its take-off position. These tugs push a bar which is linked to the nose wheel of the aircraft. Towbarless (TBL) tugs scoop up the nosewheel and lift it off the ground, allowing more-secure control and faster maneuvering.

[image: Conventional tug Goldhofer F110E]

Conventional tug [Goldhofer F110E](http://www.goldhofer.de/en/conventional,30.html) (picture [source](http://www.goldhofer.de/fileadmin/bilder/galerie/TOWBAR_Galerie_110E_Galerie_01.jpg))

[image: Boeing 777 being pulled by Goldhofer aircraft tug]

Boeing 777 being pulled by [Goldhofer](http://www.goldhofer.de/en/airport-technology,11.html) TBL aircraft tug (picture [source](http://www.pixstel.com/goldhofer-aircraft-tug_picm89-8920.jpg)). They are really hard to see when you are sitting in the cabin.

[image: Towbarless tug]

Towbarless tug detail (picture [source](http://www.airteamimages.com/pics/93/93151_800.jpg))

Comment: It is actually possible for jet aircraft to push themselves back from the gate using thrust reverse, but it is just a stupid idea to do.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann `a stupid idea to do` - it's standard practise at many regional airports.

Comment: @Simon Ah, you might want to edit this question then because it says: "Pushing back with jet engines is impossible" right above the images.

Comment: It's called a power back and it can be done. [Here is a DC9 doing it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID3jfc39x3E) and even some prop GA aircraft like the [Aviat Husky can reverse by putting the prop in beta](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.flyingmag.com/aircraft/pistons/video-reverse-taxi-husky&ved=0ahUKEwiX8KWGy97LAhXCTCYKHbTOBDkQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNF8Z_b53vRF_YplkJke8RYuGpCSfQ&sig2=Pi5CArTqEkbOReqaAISLIg)

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yes, corrected. But power backs are highly controversial. And you did note that I was speaking of jets, not turboprops, didn't you?

Comment: @PeterKämpf Yes, although I'm not sure why you mention it, the Husky is a light GA aircraft with a generic piston engine if that is what you are referring to. The DC9 is certainly equipped with Jet engines...

Answer (score 4):

During take-off roll, the aircraft tyres move due to the thrust generated by the engines (or propellers for that matter). They don't have any engines (motors) fitted inside them to help in movement. In case the engine is not producing thrust, the aircraft are towed using a tug.

Comment: I sure I saw Bombardier Dash 8 walking its way to the runway (I was in) with the propellers OFF and without any tug

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi The Dash 8 cannot move without a tug, or it's engines.

Comment: I was in, so perhaps I didint seen the tug :) . I'm not sure

Comment: Some aircraft actually do have motors inside the wheels, but this technology is still in a testing/demonstration phase.  EGTS and WheelTug are the two competing products under development.